# Apache POI XSSFFont getBold() give null pointer exception

Tags: java, apache, apache-poi, xlsx, xssf

I'm trying to check whether the font in excel is bold or not.I kept getting a null pointer exception everytime I run the code.

```
        XSSFSheet sheet1 = workbook.getSheetAt(1);
        XSSFRow row1 = sheet1.getRow(1);
        XSSFCell cell4 = row1.getCell(4);
        XSSFRichTextString val = cell4.getRichStringCellValue(); 
        System.out.println(val.toString());
        XSSFFont f = val.getFontAtIndex(0);
        System.out.println(f.getBold());    <--- this line is where the problem at
```

val.toString() is working fine. only when I run the last line f.getBold() I will get a null pointer exception, I couldn't figure out why.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [Apache POI JavaDocs on XSSFRichTextString.getFontAtIndex(int)](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFRichTextString.html#getFontAtIndex%28int%29):

> Returns:
>
> A copy of the font that's currently being applied at that index or null if no font is being applied or the index is out of range.

With a Rich Text String, a section of the string can either have a specific (different) font applied, or it can go with the default for the cell. Your code needs to handle both cases

To get the font applied, you therefore need to do something more like:

```
XSSFRichTextString val = cell4.getRichStringCellValue(); 
XSSFFont f = val.getFontAtIndex(0);
if (f == null) {
   // Default cell font applies
   XSSFCellStyle style = cell4.getCellStyle().getFont();
}
```

Comment: I check the api, XSSFRichTextString doesn't have a method that returns cell style. The content in that cell is 4 words bolded, so index 0 shouldn't be a problem. Is there any other way to check if the font is bold or not?